# How to use sound library from a yamaha keyboard

Tags: keyboard, midi, garage-band

I have connected a yamaha psr e243 keyboard to garageband, and everything works fine except that the sounds effects are totally strange: they are neither what I select on the keyboard nor those selected from garageband library.

How can I make garageband use the midi input from the keyboard directly?

Comment: MIDI can send on several channels (1-14). Are you sure, that you selected the sound for the same channel, where you received the note information?

Answer (score 2):

MIDI isn't sound, it's just information about when keys were pressed (and some other info).  If you're connecting via MIDI then you can't get the on-board sounds.  If you want the sound off the keyboard, you need to connect via audio connections.

Comment: All true, but does not explain, why the result has not the garageband-sound either.